# What factors prevent an IDE for iPad from being made?

Tags: ipad, ssh, development

It’s now common to use cloud-based IDEs like VS Code through a service like Gitpod. If the code repository is in the cloud and a service like Gitpod or Digital Ocean provides a remote machine, what are the reasons there’s no sophisticated front-end IDE like VS Code available in the App Store (which could connect via SSH like Termius)?

Comment: Because you haven't written one?

Comment: It’s possible - but since VS code hasn’t done it, it seems like there’s some kind of platform restriction. But I don’t know what the specific hurdle is.

Answer (score 2):

There are no such "platform restrictions" that prevent an IDE as described to be made for the iPad.

In fact, you can use Visual Studio Code on your iPad today and have it access a code repository in the cloud, or a remote machine on for example Digital Ocean.

For example you can open up this link in your browser:

https://github.dev/

And you'll be able to access GitHub's VS Code.

Or you could install [Visual Studio Code Server](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server) on your Digital Ocean machine and use a service such as the following to have Visual Studio Code use it:

https://vscode.dev

Here's a nifty guide on how to setup it all up based on a Tailscale private network:

https://tailscale.com/kb/1166/vscode-ipad/